# Jersey JAX-RS MessageException when using a ResponseBuilder

Tags: exception, jersey, jax-rs

When I throw a [WebApplicationException](https://jsr311.java.net/nonav/javadoc/javax/ws/rs/WebApplicationException.html) in my service like the following, I get a 404 response code which is what I'm expecting

```
throw new WebApplicationException(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND);
```

When I attempt to put a little more information in my exception via a [ResponseBuilder](https://jsr311.java.net/nonav/releases/0.2/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.Builder.html), I'm getting a 500 response code.  Here's my enhanced code and the response message I get back:

```
List<Error> errors = new ArrayList<>();
errors.add(new Error(ErrorCode.PDF_GENERATION_ERROR));
ErrorResponse errResponse = new ErrorResponse();
errResponse.setErrors(errors);
throw new WebApplicationException(Response.status(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND).entity(errResponse).build());
```

> javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException:
>   com.sun.jersey.api.MessageExceptio n: A message body writer for Java
>   class idexx.ordering.rest.common.types.ErrorRe sponse, and Java type
>   class idexx.ordering.rest.common.types.ErrorResponse, and MIME media
>   type application/octet-stream was not found

My REST service has the following method signature:

```
@Produces("application/pdf")
@GET
@Path("/{id}")
public Response getPdfById(@PathParam("id") final Long id) {
```

Is there anyway I can get that extra error code information into the response when I throw a WebApplicationException?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String errResponse = "convert your errors to text";
throw new WebApplicationException(Response.status(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND).entity(errResponse).build());
```

Probably this will work because JAX-RS can convert basic types, but to convert `List<Error>` you need to register a custom `MessageBodyWriter`.